# Why are suggested edits that were rejected as spam or vandalism not visible to users who don't have an account on the site?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, spam

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207837/349538) links to four suggested edits that were rejected as spam on Gaming Stack Exchange, a site where I don't have any account. I was surprised to see that when I tried to see those suggested edits, it gave me a 404 page. However, I could see [this suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/159403) on Gaming Stack Exchange although I don't have any account there, the only difference being that that one was rejected for another reason than spam and the other ones were rejected as spam. So I can see all suggested edits on Gaming Stack Exchange, except those that were rejected as spam. I also created an account on Gaming Stack Exchange with a sock puppet that has 1 reputation, and then I could see those edits. So a user who has 1 reputation can see those edits, but not a user who has no account at all.

That made my think that edits rejected as spam or vandalism can only be seen by users who have an account on the site, no matter their reputation. To be sure that my theory is correct and is true on all Stack Exchange sites, I suggested [this edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/54020) with a sock puppet and asked the reviewers to reject it as spam or vandalism (which they did). Then I logged out to see if I could see it when I'm not logged in, and I couldn't. So apparently, all suggested edits are visible to anyone who has the URL, except edits rejected as spam or vandalism which are only visible to users who have an account on the site, no matter their reputation.

Why are edits that were rejected as spam or vandalism not visible to users who don't have any account on the site? Is there any reason for this? Is it a bug?

Comment: I would guest that its part of an antispam strategy, to not allow unauthenticated bot to detect their rejected edit

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346542/4751173

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is by design.

The theory is that spammers have clients - and that they need to show them the spam *without* having to have their clients create an account and login.

If they can't show the spam to their clients... less incentive to post suggested edit spam.