# Restrict the access to suggested edit reviews on deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, spam, deleted-posts

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18790609) on an answer deleted as rude/abusive is visible, even without logging in (and for users with less than 10k reputation). These users can't see the answer ['directly'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734701), via the [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48734701/revisions), or a direct link to the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4638c65f-ce5b-4616-a9ca-f0d88789c38c/view-source).

[image]

This is a potential avenue for spammers, just like the suggested edit spam *used* to be, but is [no longer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346542/4751173); according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/295232):

> In addition, in order to reduce the incentive for spammers to make spam edits that get rejected, suggested edit spam is hidden from logged-out users, so they can't show their clients public-facing pages with spam (so they won't get paid).

For this to work, the spammer would need two accounts, one to post the spam and a second one to suggest an edit. Even if the spam post is quickly nuked, the review link will be active forever. One could argue that logged-in users without 10k reputation shouldn't be able to see the suggested edits either; I'm partial to that.

Comment: As an aside, why is this rude/abusive? Surely it is NAA?

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to not let registered users with less than 10k reputation see those edits. It's not like they see those posts just like that when they're browsing the site, they still need the link (which they would probably get on Meta). But I do agree that anonymous users shouldn't be able to see those edits for the reasons mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300946/349538).

Comment: It's rude/abusive because it contains [no useful content at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/295232). It's highly unlikely that this user will ever try to post a proper answer; it's more likely they will produce another bogus post like this, and thanks to the IP ban it's now a lot harder for them.

Comment: Is this very much of an issue? Following a recent change, rejected edits containing spam show as fake 404 errors to logged-out users. Do you have any documented cases where they continue to be visible to the public?

Comment: @SonicWizard I can still see that suggested edit when logged out. I think the change you describe only affects suggested edits which *themselves* are rejected as spam/vandalism.

Comment: I guess this is one reason why the team retained a 10-minute age requirement on anonymous edits on brand new posts - so they'd have to create a new account to make a suggestion.