# Deleted questions (maybe answers too) are visible in the suggested edit review queue for all users

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

When reviewing the suggested edits on AU, I noticed that question is deleted but still had a pending suggested edit, then I tried to see if this post is visible for me as I'm >10K or not and surprisingly when I open the review task in "incognito mode" I can see the deleted question but when I click title of the question there it redirects me to a deleted post page.

I doubt if this a bug and should not be visible to all users at least, except for >10K rep users.

link to task:  https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1136755

timeline of the question:

[image: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1330836/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries]

Comment: I proposed a related feature request: [Restrict the access to suggested edit reviews on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306875/295232)

Comment: Perhaps; I just don't want to do that singlehandedly...

Comment: Does anyone see this review? https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/77776

Comment: @Luuklag when logged in, yes (but I have 10k); when not logged in, no. The behaviour described here only applies to suggested edit reviews, not other types.

Comment: While Glorfindel didn't want to close single-handedly... I just did. It's not really a bug since it's known behavior, which leaves the request to not make these visible to all users. That's similar enough to Glorfindel's request, though if you have different ideas on how you'd like to see that restriction implemented, an answer to that post is a good idea :)